# In R need count of consecutive years played

Tags: r, dplyr

I need to know for each player who played for the New York Mets (NYM) how many consecutive years they played, starting with the year they first joined the team.

**Sample Input**

[image: Sample Input]

In the sample output below, there is an error I need fixed. Player C started playing for the Mets in 1984 (see Sample Input above), but his first stint with the team ended in 1987 as he did not play for them in 1988, so though the Sample Output shows it as 5 consecutive years, it should be 4.

I would prefer a dplyr solution but am open to others.

I checked the available stackoverflow solutions, but could not find one that directly addressed my situation. If one exists, I would appreciate it if you could share its link.

**Sample Output**

[image: Sample Output]

**Here is my code so far:**

```
cym |>
  filter(Team == "NYM") |>
  group_by(Player) |>
  count(name = "Consec_Yrs")
```

**Dput(cym):**

```
structure(list(Player = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "D"), Team = c("NYM", 
"NYM", "LAD", "LAD", "SFG", "NYM", "NYM", "NYM", "PHA", "NYM", 
"NYM", "NYM", "NYM", "ATL", "ATL", "NYM", "NYM"), Year = c(1970, 
1971, 1972, 1973, 1980, 1980, 1981, 1982, 1983, 1984, 1985, 1986, 
1987, 1987, 1988, 1989, 2000)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -17L))
```

Comment: @akrun What other options are you thinking of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may need to create a grouping based on the consecutive years

```
library(dplyr)
out <- cym %>%
   group_by(Team, Player) %>%
   mutate(grpYear = cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(Year) != 1))) %>% 
   group_by(grpYear, .add = TRUE)  %>%
   count(name = "Consec_Yrs") %>%
   ungroup
```

-output

```
> out %>% filter(Team == "NYM")
# A tibble: 5 × 4
  Team  Player grpYear Consec_Yrs
  <chr> <chr>    <int>      <int>
1 NYM   A            1          2
2 NYM   B            1          3
3 NYM   C            1          4
4 NYM   C            2          1
5 NYM   D            1          1
```

---

If we want only a single `max` consecutive count per group, then

```
out %>% 
  group_by(Team, Player) %>%
  slice_max(n = 1, order_by = Consec_Yrs) %>%
  ungroup
# A tibble: 8 × 4
  Team  Player grpYear Consec_Yrs
  <chr> <chr>    <int>      <int>
1 ATL   C            1          2
2 LAD   A            1          2
3 NYM   A            1          2
4 NYM   B            1          3
5 NYM   C            1          4
6 NYM   D            1          1
7 PHA   C            1          1
8 SFG   B            1          1
```

Comment: In `mutate(grpYear = cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(Year) != 1))) `how does the `cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(Year) != 1))` part work?

Comment: @Metsfan `diff(year)` returns the difference of adjacent 'year' elements (length one less than original length), convert it to logical `!= 1`, i.e difference between adjancent is not equal to 1, concatenate TRUE at the beginning (to adjust the length) and take the cumulative sum, so that whereever there is difference not equal to 1, it will increment by 1 (TRUE ->1 and FALSE -> 0)

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(Player, Team) %>% 
  mutate(aux = cumsum(c(1, diff(Year) == 1))) %>% 
  summarise(Consec_yrs = max(aux), .groups = "drop")

#> # A tibble: 8 × 3
#>   Player Team  Consec_yrs
#>   <chr>  <chr>      <dbl>
#> 1 A      LAD            2
#> 2 A      NYM            2
#> 3 B      NYM            3
#> 4 B      SFG            1
#> 5 C      ATL            2
#> 6 C      NYM            4
#> 7 C      PHA            1
#> 8 D      NYM            1
```

Comment: The way you presented the output creates an interesting situation because Player B played for both the Mets and the Giants (SFG) in the same season--1980--and for only three years. How else could your output be shown?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @Metsfan. Unfortunately, I does not quite understand it. Could you please be more specific?

Comment: In 1980, Player B played for two teams, NYM and SFG, starting the year playing for SFG and then, in the same season, playing for NYM. Your output makes it appear that he played three seasons for the Mets and then, after that, a fourth season for the Giants. Hope that helps.

Comment: I now understand your previous comment, but it is still unclear what is the output that you would like to have, @Metsfan.

Comment: As your output contains the correct information for the Mets, the main focus of this post, let's keep it as it is. The issue is what to do when a player plays for two different teams in the same season as Player B did.

Comment: That is ok, @Metsfan. Once you have defined what the output should be in such cases, you may want to come back to StackOverflow, to ask for help, if needed.